# RTP Capture through java

Tags: java, rtp

I was wondering if it would be possible to read rtp packets from a ipaddress:port.
I have all the information as to where the rtp is from.
I could listen to it from wire shark.
What I want to do is capture those RTP packets and write them into file.

I've been looking at JMF and I think this is the way to go.
I would like to know if anyone has made some sample code to implement this requirement.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at my [RTP2DASH](https://github.com/sannies/rtp2dash) project. JMF is as outdated as it gets - don't use it (even if my advice might be a bit late).

The RTP2DASH project reads AAC and H264 RTP packets and re-emits an MPEG-DASH stream but it might be easily adopted to simple write MP4 files (as MPEG-DASH is MP4 based)

Good luck!
Sebastian